# Yahoo placefinder with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to use yahoo placefinder on my website to find people's location, but it's not working. I must be doing something wrong, but I can't work out what.

I have the following code:

```
new Request.HTML({ method: 'get', url: 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=1600+Pennsylvania+Avenue,+Washington,+DC&appid=KGe6P34c',
    onSuccess: function () {
        console.log("aaa");
    }
}).send();
```

The `onSuccess` function is never called. Using firebug, I can see that the request has been sent, and that some kind of response is received. I receive these response headers:

```
Date: Tue, 23 Aug 2011 09:51:18 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
X-Yahoo-Serving-Host: wws2.geotech.ch1.yahoo.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
```

but the body of the response is empty.

The weird thing is that if I type the [request URL](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Avenue,%20Washington,%20DC&appid=KGe6P34c) into my web browser I receive a normal XML response. I am also using the placefinder service server side at one point with no problems:

```
    String reqURL = "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?postal=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postCode) + "&Country=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(countryCode) + "&appid=KGe6P34c";
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(reqURL);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing a cross-domain XHR request, which is not allowed due to security policies.

workarounds are:

- use JSONP - though place finder does not provide an api for it, only JSON, XML or RAW - http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/responses.html#supported-formats To get it going, you can code your own local proxy that fetches the JSON or any response and produces it via a `callback=` wrapper or raw for a simple `Request.HTML` response.
- use YQL which does work with JSONP: http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/PlaceFinder-General-Discussion/YQL-for-JSONP-support/1277520863000-c962d7bf-ec1f-314c-856a-3c0402e1d4cb

Plenty of examples around that provide code for YQL + MOOTOOLS + JSONP though I'd question my business logic and use here - being reliant on not 1 but 2 yahoo-powered services is very near sighted and high/critical performance cannot be guaranteed or expected.

Remember the running joke that the fastest way to get any service shut down is to get yahoo to buy it.

An example via extending Request.JSONP from mootools-more:

```
Request.GeoData = new Class({

    Extends: Request.JSONP,

    options: {
        url: "http://geoip.pidgets.com/?format=json"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.parent(options);
        if (this.options.ip) {
            this.options.url += "&ip=" + this.options.ip;
        }
    }

});

new Request.GeoData({
    // default ip = client
    onComplete: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}).send();

new Request.GeoData({
    // hardwire an ip to check for:
    ip: "87.106.181.42",
    onComplete: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}).send();
```

you can use YQL to elaborate further:

```
Request.getPlaceInfo = new Class({
    // return json data with extended information of a place / location.
    Extends: Request.JSONP,
    options: {
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from geo.places where text='{location}'&format=json",
    },
    initialize: function(location, options) {
        this.parent(options);
        this.options.url = this.options.url.substitute({location: location});
    },
    success: function(data, script) {
        this.parent(data, script);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ouch, thanks for the heads up. I only tried to use yahoo's service because google's geocoder doesn't work for the Channel Islands, where my company is based. I guess I'll look for another solution.

Comment: here's an example code for JSONP - enabled geolocation service I tend to use: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/7KHKF/